# It is ok to ask questions involving tmux, terminal, or iTerm 2?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Tmux is often used in conjunction with vim, and sometimes I don't even know if the problem I'm experiencing is with vim, tmux, or my terminal.

So, is it ok to ask questions about tmux, or the terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the question. The question should be *about Vi*, or *about Vi* interacting with tmux or a terminal emulator.

*Off-topic* questions would be:

- How do I rebind the prefix key in `tmux`?
- How do I make my fonts larger in `xterm`?

These questions don't really have anything to do with vi or vim.

*On-topic* questions might be:

- [Tmux is changing part of the background in vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/238/tmux-is-changing-part-of-the-background-in-vim/247)
- Backspace doesn't work in Vim when using `xterm`, but works fine in `gnome-terminal`

These questions deal with various problems that happpens when you use Vim in combination with tmux or a terminal emulator.